# When I am using .map for getting API return, the response that I got is payload, how to get real data from mapping call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const requestURL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments`;
  const gg = apis1.map(ap => {
    const repos =  call(request, requestURL+ap.etc)
    return repos;
  })
  console.log(gg)
```

I was wondering if I use .map, I can't get the real data, It was payload, how can I get the real data if I use .Map?

Comment: Can you show the code that does not use `map` and does get the "real data", please?

Comment: Please show us the code of that `call` method. What does it do? What does it return?

Comment: Why are you using `map` at all? The `call(…)` doesn't even use the array element `ap`!

Comment: I use map, to put all the response and store in ArrayList

Comment: You can also do that using `const gg = [call(request, requestURL)]` - the response in an array.

Comment: I have a parameter etc in apis1, that's why I need to map each row in my apis1

Comment: But not in the code you posted in your question? Please [edit] it to include a [mcve], as close to your real code as possible.